# convert rows as column (like PIVOT) is not working if the number of values increases in SQL Server

Tags: sql

I want to convert rows as column (like PIVOT) and i am unable to get if the number of values increases.

Below is my table.

[image: Table1]

i want the output like this.

[image: Table2]

I have used the following queries to acheive this but no luck.

Query1

```
Create table #temp(instanceid int, submissionid int, name1 varchar(20), value1 varchar(20))

insert into #temp(instanceid,submissionid,name1,value1)
Select 5151,5532,'Question_1','Y'
union
Select 5151,5532,'First','Mujda'
union
Select 5151,5532,'Last','Zhublawar'
union
Select 5151,5532,'Question_1','Y'
union
Select 5151,5532,'First','Mujda1'
union
Select 5151,5532,'Last','Zhublawar1'
union
Select 5151,5532,'Question_1','Y'
union
Select 5152,5533,'First','Muthu'
union
Select 5151,5533,'Last','Kumar'
union
Select 5152,5533,'Question_1','Y'
union
Select 5152,5533,'First','Muthu1'
union
Select 5152,5533,'Last','Kumar1'


GO

DECLARE   @SQLQuery AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE   @PivotColumns AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE   @PivotValues AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

--Get unique values of pivot column  
SELECT   @PivotColumns= COALESCE(@PivotColumns + ',','') + QUOTENAME(seq)
FROM (
select (cast(row_number() over(partition by name1 order by name1) as varchar(10)) + name1) as seq
from #temp group by value1,name1,instanceid
) AS PivotExample


--Create the dynamic query with all the values for 
--pivot column at runtime
SET   @SQLQuery = 
    N'SELECT instanceid,submissionid, ' +   @PivotColumns + '
    FROM #temp 
    PIVOT( MAX(value1) 
          FOR name1 IN (' + @PivotColumns + ')) AS P'

--Execute dynamic query
EXEC sp_executesql @SQLQuery

DROP TABLE #temp
```

Query2:

```
Create table #temp(instanceid int, submissionid int, name1 varchar(20), value1 varchar(20))

insert into #temp(instanceid,submissionid,name1,value1)
Select 5151,5532,'Question_1','Y'
union
Select 5151,5532,'First','Mujda'
union
Select 5151,5532,'Last','Zhublawar'
union
Select 5151,5532,'Interest','100'

select * from(
Select 
instanceid,
submissionid,
[1st Ownership First Name] = Case when name1='First' then value1 end,
[1st Ownership Last Name] = Case when name1='Last' then value1 end,
[1st Ownership Question] = Case when name1='Question_1' then value1 end
from #temp 
group by instanceid,submissionid,name1,value1
) P where p.[1st Ownership First Name] is not null or p.[1st Ownership Last Name] is not null or p.[1st Ownership Question] is not null


drop table #temp
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need an extra field to get some order in that data with all the duplicates.
For example a primary key.

Then you can use a pivot with a row_number that uses that extra field in the order by.
Then concat the row_number with the name1, and Pivot on those.

For example :

```
create table #temp (id int identity(1,1), instanceid int, submissionid int, name1 varchar(20), value1 varchar(20));

insert into #temp(instanceid,submissionid,name1,value1) values
(5151,5532,'First','Mujda'),
(5151,5532,'Last','Zhublawar'),
(5151,5532,'Question_1','Y'),
(5151,5532,'First','Mujda1'),
(5151,5532,'Last','Zhublawar1'),
(5151,5532,'Question_1','Y'),
(5151,5532,'First','Mujda1'),
(5151,5532,'Last','Zhublawar1'),
(5151,5532,'Question_1','Y'),
(5151,5533,'First','Muthu'),
(5151,5533,'Last','Kumar'),
(5151,5533,'Question_1','Y'),
(5151,5534,'First','Suresh'),
(5151,5534,'Last','Kumar'),
(5151,5534,'Question_1','Y'),
(5151,5534,'First','Suresh1'),
(5151,5534,'Last','Kumar1'),
(5151,5534,'Question_1','Y');

SELECT 
instanceid,
submissionid, 
[First1] as [1st First], [Last1] as [1st Last], [Question_11] as [1st Question_1],
[First2] as [2nd First], [Last2] as [2nd Last], [Question_12] as [2nd Question_1],
[First3] as [3rd First], [Last3] as [3rd Last], [Question_13] as [3rd Question_1]
FROM (
    select 
    instanceid, 
    submissionid, 
    concat(name1, row_number() over (partition by instanceid, submissionid, name1 order by id)) as name_rn, value1 
    from #temp
    where name1 in ('First','Last','Question_1')
    ) t
PIVOT( MAX(value1)
FOR name_rn IN (
    [First1], [Last1], [Question_11], 
    [First2], [Last2], [Question_12], 
    [First3], [Last3], [Question_13]
    )
) AS Pvt;
```

To do it the dynamic way, here's some SQL to generate a @SQL variable.

```
declare @T table (name1 varchar(20));

insert into @T select name1 from #temp group by name1 order by name1;

declare @SQL nvarchar(max);
declare @Fields1 nvarchar(max);
declare @Fields2 nvarchar(max);

SELECT @Fields2 = STUFF((select ', ' + quotename(name1) from @T order by name1 FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'');
SET @Fields2 = replace(@Fields2,']','1]')+','+char(13)+replace(@Fields2,']','2]')+','+char(13)+replace(@Fields2,']','3]');

SELECT @Fields1 = STUFF((select ',$' + quotename(name1+n)+' as '+quotename(nx+' '+name1) from (
    select '1' as n, '1st' as nx, name1 from @T union all 
    select '2', '2nd' as nx, name1 from @T union all 
    select '3', '3rd' as nx, name1 from @T
    ) q order by n, name1 FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'');
SET @Fields1 = replace(@Fields1,'$',char(13));

SET @SQL = 
'SELECT 
instanceid,
submissionid,'+@Fields1+'
FROM (
    select 
    instanceid, 
    submissionid, 
    concat(name1, row_number() over (partition by instanceid, submissionid, name1 order by id)) as name_rn, value1 
    from #temp
    ) t
PIVOT( MAX(value1)
FOR name_rn IN ('+char(13)+@Fields2+')
) AS Pvt';

select @SQL;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
--Get unique values of pivot column  
SELECT   @PivotColumns= COALESCE(@PivotColumns + ',','') + QUOTENAME(seq)
FROM (
select DISTINCT (name1) as seq
from #temp group by value1,name1,instanceid
) AS PivotExample
```

This are is your problem you are concatenating a row_number into the name1 value which would always be null.  Your column list needs to be the DISTINCT values in name1 NOT what you want them to be in the end.  If you want to rename columns you would alias them after the pivot or change the value in name1 prior to running the pivot.

So in the above code I removed the `ROW_NUMBER()` and added `DISTINCT` to the derived table.

Also note the test data you included has some instanceid & submissionid combinations that are missing certain fields like first name, or question.  It looks like when copying and pasting you just didn't correct the correlations.